# Data won't appear on Report based on criteria chosen in multiple Combo Boxes

Tags: ms-access

I am really not a pro in access and i would really appreciate any help that i can get with this.

I have a Form which acts as a Menu Page for a report. The form has 2 Combo boxes, combo2 is filtered based on the value chosen in combo1. It also has a text box that is auto-populated with a data based on what has been chosen in combo2.

I have included pictures to better illustriate my issue:

[image: Report Menu Page (Form) Design View]

For the report, it gets its data from a query

In the "Record Source" of the Property Sheet has this:

```
SELECT Daily_Material.Part_Name
    ,Daily_Material.Part_Number
    ,Daily_Material.Material_Description
    ,Daily_Material.Customer_Name
    ,*
FROM Daily_Material
WHERE (
        ((Daily_Material.Part_Name) = Forms ! [6a_Generate_Daily_Material_Record] ! cboPart_Name1)
        AND ((Daily_Material.Part_Number) = Forms ! [6a_Generate_Daily_Material_Record] ! txtPart_Number)
        AND ((Daily_Material.Material_Description) = Forms ! [6a_Generate_Daily_Material_Record] ! cboMaterial_Description1)
        AND (
            (DateValue((Daily_Material.Date_Recorded))) BETWEEN DateValue(Forms ! [6a_Generate_Daily_Material_Record] ! Date_Recorded)
                AND DateValue(Forms ! [6a_Generate_Daily_Material_Record] ! Date_Recorded2)
            )
        AND ((Daily_Material.Customer_Name) = Forms ! [6a_Generate_Daily_Material_Record] ! cboCustomer_Name1)
        );
```

What is suppose to happen is that the user would chose the criterias in the Form, e.g. Start Date, End Date, Customer Name, Part Name, Part Number, & Material Description. From there the user would click a button that opens the Report and the report would then show the data between the dates. But it does not work somehow, no data is showing.

Could it be the fact that the combo box in the form has multiple columns? i did however, tried to edit one of the codes in the query to

```
`[Forms]![6a_Generate_Daily_Material_Record]![cboCustomer_Name1].Column(1)`
```

but it did not solve the issue. If anyone has an idead on how i should solve this, i would really appreciate it thank you.

Comment: As a start, you need to edit not one but _all_ of your forms statements.

Comment: Instead of joining Customer Name with your combo, join the combo with it's corresponding ID field. Combobox references return the bound column which is usually an ID field. Figure out which field is outputted when you reference your combo and then replace the table column so it matches the output. It will be the first column listed in the combo's row source. The `.Column()` property is not available in queries, only available in VBA and macros.